# Power shell Script to update CSV file date time fields from UTC to local time

Tags: powershell, timezone, salesforce

We have an automatic scheduled export of Salesforce data into CSV files in specific folder(everyday at 10pm).

In each CSV file there are two datetime columns which are in UTC time format `[2018-01-30T05:27:26.000Z]`.

My requirement is to create a script to read those CSV files and update date time columns into local time zone and format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss).

And I need to schedule this script to run everyday (everyday at 10.30pm). 
(we know the folder path, file name, column name).

Please help with the script sample.
Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a script writing community. The goal of Stackoverflow is to help people improve, or correct errors in what they have already tried.  With that being said, have you tried taking the field and converting it to date time? by putting [datetime] at the beginning of it.  `[datetime]"2018-01-30T05:27:26.000Z"` produces a localtime instead of the utc time. Maybe you can start there.

Comment: @Kiran - changing those fields to the backwards EU date format is ... not a good idea. if the people who are using this are unable to deal with consistent, sane, reliable date formats ... then you may want to **_ADD_** an EU formatted column for their [unfortunately brain damaged] use. [*grin*]  /////  
seriously, try to avoid introducing date formats that are purely local.  /////  
if you need the local time, use the builtin `[datetime]` methods for doing that ... but try to retain the logical, reliable, non-insane `yyyy-MM-dd` layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditto to what Robert Cotterman has stated.

However, with This well could be considered a duplicate of this discussion.

[Convert list of UTC to Current TimeZone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87604/convert-list-of-utc-to-current-timezone)

```
$UTCTime = GC "C:\Scripts\UTC.txt"
$results = '' | Select UTCTime,PST
Foreach ($newtime in $UTCTime){
$strCurrentTimeZone = (Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName
$TZ = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($strCurrentTimeZone)
$LocalTime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($newtime, $TZ)
$results.UTCTime = $newtime
$results.PST = $LocalTime
 $results
}
```

This answer will get you started, and that last part is just use the script with a scheduled task.